# Why can't I use LINQ to get the XML elements in WinRT?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, windows-8, windows-runtime

**1.What I want**
get proper xml elements out of a xml file

**The XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tasks>
  <task>
    <title>Test0001</title>
    <due>06/17/2012</due>
  </task>
  <task>
    <title>Test0002</title>
    <due>06/17/2012</due>
  </task>
  <task>
    <title>Test0003</title>
    <due>06/17/2012</due>
  </task>
<tasks>
```

**2.what I code**

The Linq block:

```
        StorageFile file1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("BetterTask.xml");
        XDocument doc1 = new XDocument();
        using (var ReadStream1 = await file1.OpenStreamForReadAsync() as Stream)
        {
            doc1 = XDocument.Load(ReadStream1);
        }


        var data = from query in doc1.Descendants("task")
                   select new mytask
                   {
                       title = (string)query.Element("title"),
                       due = (string)query.Element("due")
                   };

        List<mytask> myTasks = data.ToList();
        myTodayListBox.ItemsSource = myTasks;
```

the mytask Class

```
public class mytask
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string due { get; set; }
}
```

**3.What I get**
I set a break at the last of the block, when the app break, i found in the LinQ part:
<1>the [doc1] is full of the XML content
<2>but [myTasks] is empty(count = 0),....

**4. Why and how to solve**
:(

Comment: Do you mean `data` is empty or `myTasks` is empty? `data` will be empty because it's been enumerated, but all the values should be in `myTasks`.

Comment: Is that actually your XML? Doesn't your XML use namespaces by any chance?

Comment: yep, myTasks is empty, its count = 0 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the variable `doc1` in your case actually refers the document itself. You will have to do something like:

```
doc1.Root.Descendants("task")
```

to get it to work.

Comment: But `Descendants("task")` on `XDocument` should work just as well. This shouldn't change anything.

Comment: But it works @svick , without the added "Root", the block doesn't work again

Comment: I think if you don't use "Root" you may have to use `Descendants("//task")`